# Laravel - Action not defined

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb

I create a CRUD application in Laravel 7 and MongoDB. Adding items to the collection works fine. But I wanted to delete an item and unfortunately Laravel stopped liking me... I get an error:

```
Action App\Http\Controllers\InQuestController@destroy not defined.
```

I checked a dozen times and wrote such a function

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Quests;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class InQuestsController extends Controller
{
    ...

    public function destroy($id) {
        $quest = Quests::find($id);
        $quest->delete();

        return redirect('inside');
    }
}
```

To function I am reffering from:

```
<form action="{{ action('InQuestsController@destroy', $quest->id) }}" method="POST">
      @csrf
      <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">
      <button id="details" class="idButton detailsButton" type="button"><img src="{{ asset('images/arrow.png') }}" alt="" class="icon arrow"></button>
      <button class="editButton" type="button"><img src="{{ asset('images/pencil.svg') }}" alt=""></button>
      <button class="deleteButton" type="submit"> <img src="{{ asset('images/bin.png') }}" alt=""></button>
</form>
```

What's wrong?

Comment: `InQuestsController` != `InQuestController`  fix this  here `Action App\Http\Controllers\InQuestController@destroy not defined.`

Comment: Fixed, but the error is still the same

Comment: same error .?  `Action App\Http\Controllers\InQuestController@destroy not defined` ?

Comment: @KamleshPaul Yes, this same. But "Quest" is now "Quests" in error description ->   Action App\Http\Controllers\InQuestsController@destroy not defined.

Comment: then use URL instead of direct controller action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIX:

In ***web.php*** add line:

```
Route::delete('{id}', 'InQuestsController@destroy')->name('destroy');
```